# Create sub-calendar in android primary google calendar account in android

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to send request from main Google Calendar account to create a sub-calendar, known as friend's calendar, using Google API in Android (programatically).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Calendar API [Java Client Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) in your app to INSERT a new calendar.

If you use Gradle, you can put `compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc'` in dependencies to get the client library.

You can follow [this example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert) to insert a new calendar. After you insert a new calendar, you can use Calendar Provider to [retrieve the new calendar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#query), or use Google Calendar API's [GET method](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) to retrieve the new calendar.